# Upload bounding boxes Pascal VOC along with IMG files

Tags: google-cloud-ml

While uploading the IMG files, I am thinking about uploading the respective bounding box data as well through Pascal VOC files.  How can I do that on Vertex AI or do I need to do any transformation of the Pascal VOC data?

Answer (score 0):

You can do object detection using [AutoML Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision) which is available for Vertex-AI.
Preparing training dataset for Object detection in AutoML Vision requires your data to be in .csv format.
You can refer to this [link](https://roboflow.com/convert/pascal-voc-xml-to-cloud-automl-vision-csv) to convert your Pascal VOC files to Cloud AutoML Vision csv.

To prepare and format data for object detection:

- Prepare your training data according to the supported image files and
  bounding box requirements mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/prepare).
- After preparing training data  you can then create a CSV file with bounding boxes. [Doc](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/csv-format)

For more details on how to build  object detection models on AutoML Vision follow this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/quickstart-ui).

Answer (score 0):

> You can refer to this link to convert your Pascal VOC files to Cloud
> AutoML Vision csv.

This requires upgraded membership of roboflow.com. Following code serves the purpose locally on your machine!

Note: It requires you to have your images and annotations (xml files) stored on a GCS bucket.

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET



os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']= 'path-to-credentials-json-file'

bucket_name = 'your-bucket-name'

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

blobs = client.list_blobs(bucket_name,prefix=None,delimiter='/')

#download all xmls files to local directory or one can paste all the xmls in current working directory and comment downloading part
print('Downloading xml files...')
xml_files = [blob.name for blob in blobs if blob.name.endswith('.xml')]
[bucket.blob(xml).download_to_filename(xml) for xml in xml_files]


allowed_extensions = ['jpg','png','jpeg','gif','bmp','ico']


csv_file_name = 'vertex_ai_annos.csv'
csvfile = open(csv_file_name,'w', newline='')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, escapechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

blobs = client.list_blobs(bucket_name,prefix=None,delimiter='/') #reinitialize list_blobs iterator
for blob in blobs:
    ext = blob.name.split('.')[-1]
    if ext in allowed_extensions:
        tree = ET.parse(f"{blob.name.split('.')[0]}.xml")
        width = int(tree.find('size').find('width').text)
        height = int(tree.find('size').find('height').text)

        objs = tree.findall('object')
        for obj in objs:
            label = obj.find('name').text
            xmin = int(obj.find('bndbox').find('xmin').text)/width
            ymin = int(obj.find('bndbox').find('ymin').text)/height
            xmax = int(obj.find('bndbox').find('xmax').text)/width
            ymax = int(obj.find('bndbox').find('ymax').text)/height
            data = f"gs://{bucket_name}/{blob.name},{label},{xmin},{ymin},,,{xmax},{ymax},,"
            # print(data)
            csvwriter.writerow([f'gs://{bucket_name}/{blob.name},{label},{xmin},{ymin},,,{xmax},{ymax},,'])

print(f'{csv_file_name} has been created!')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Local directory where your XML files are located
local_xml_directory = 'pathtoxmlfiles'

# Google Cloud Storage bucket name
bucket_name = 'googlebucketname'
# The path to the folder in the bucket where the images are stored
bucket_image_folder = 'pathwherefilesstoreinbucket'

xml_files = [f for f in os.listdir(local_xml_directory) if f.endswith('.xml')]
allowed_extensions = ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'bmp', 'ico']

csv_file_name = 'vertex_ai_annos.csv'
csvfile = open(csv_file_name, 'w', newline='')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, escapechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

for xml_file in xml_files:
    xml_file_path = os.path.join(local_xml_directory, xml_file)
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    image_filename = root.find('filename').text
    image_gcs_url = f'gs://{bucket_name}/{bucket_image_folder}{image_filename}'
    size = root.find('size')
    width = int(size.find('width').text)
    height = int(size.find('height').text)
    objects = root.findall('object')
    for obj in objects:
        label = obj.find('name').text
        bndbox = obj.find('bndbox')
        xmin = int(bndbox.find('xmin').text) / width
        ymin = int(bndbox.find('ymin').text) / height
        xmax = int(bndbox.find('xmax').text) / width
        ymax = int(bndbox.find('ymax').text) / height

        csvwriter.writerow([image_gcs_url, label, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymin, xmax, ymax, xmin, ymax])

print(f'{csv_file_name} has been created!')
```

This code works for generating a local CSV file that you can upload directly into cloud vertex for all Pascal VOC XML files